# SharePoint 2013 Workflow gets canceled automatically

Tags: sharepoint, ssl-certificate, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

Please help me in fixing Workflow cancelled error. This error appeared when moving to the Online server with **SSL Protocol** (https), note that we use an SSL certificate.

This is the error:

> RequestorId: 87baaf2c-4222-8dc2-e619-7223d6d28fce. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401 The page cannot be displayed
>
> Explanation: There is a problem with the page you are trying to reach
>   and it cannot be displayed. Try the following:
>
> Refresh page: Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh
>   button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion.
>   Check spelling: Check that you typed the Web page address correctly.
>   The address may have been mistyped. Access from a link: If there is a
>   link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that
>   link.
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>   Error Code: 401 Unauthorized. The server requires authorization to
>   fulfill the request. Access to the Web server is denied. Contact the
>   server administrator. (12209)
>
> {"Connection":["Keep-Alive"],"Pragma":["no-cache"],"Cache-Control":["no-cache"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic
>   Realm=\"portal.test.com\""]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Convert all "http"s to "https" in your workflow and deploy wf again.

I hope it helps.